# What was the point of eating and drinking?

Tags: plot-explanation, oculus

In [Oculus (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2388715/), Kaylie sets up a few alarms for her and her brother to perform various tasks. One of them is to eat and another is to hydrate (drink water). They were ~60 minute alarms.

I didn't recognize any explanation of why they had to eat and drink so often. I recall that Kaylie explained a few of the mirror's victims and the way they died, one was a woman who died in her bathtub of dehydration (even though she soaked for 3 days) and another gentleman who purchased the mirror at one time was over 300lbs but had been photographed later and was depicted as a very thin man. I believe he died as a result.

Other than that, I don't recall any explanation as to why they had to eat and drink so often. What was the point?

Comment: You already answered you question. I can't see the point of question now. Please explain.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I think you're thinking *"They had to eat and hydrate often **reason** else they'd die"* but the OP is asking what *caused* them to be so hungry & thirsty.  Either that or I don't really understand your comment..

Comment: @AndrewThompson she was studying the house from a long and want to eliminate all reason of previous death. So that's itself is an answer.

Comment: @AnkitSharma If that is the answer (and it makes sense), it wasn't explicitly explained by the movie, at least in a way that I caught.

Comment: @DustinDavis: Just to check, did either of these answers address what you were after? Or are you still hoping for a better explanation?

Comment: @AndrewMartin Forgot about this question. I was able to possibly imply an answer to my satisfaction based on chaitanya89's answer.

Comment: @DustinDavis: Perfect. Just looking through some of these older questions and trying to get them shut!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why the alarms to eat and drink?**

Kaylie learned from her research that some of the past owners of the mirror died from starvation and dehydration.

**Why so often? (my personal interpretation)**

Kaylie knows that the mirror is manipulative and the persons around it have delusions and lose control over time. She also believes that the mirror feeds on the life around it, so she experiments with a dog to prove it to her brother and we see that plants losing life and it also controls electricity.

Kaylie is being overprotective of herself and her brother. She believes that the mirror feeds on life (examples: experiment with dog, plants losing life). So, she might of thought it's best to eat and hydrate very often.

There's this [review](http://www.janelcomeau.ca/2014/05/overanalyzing-oculus-how-to-survive.html) which you might find interesting. The reviewer says that all the safety measures Kaylie has taken are useless.

> This mirror works primarily by messing with its victims' sensation of time and space. It makes you see things that aren't there, hear things that aren't real, and experience things differently from how they're actually unfolding. Sure, there's some sort of woman/demon/toothless ghost monster living in the mirror, but she doesn't seem to want to come out unless it is absolutely necessary. Normally, just messing with your perception does the trick. Which means there's a huge problem with Kaylie's "get over here and eat a granola bar" alarm strategy; it only works if Kaylie and Tim are lucid enough to hear it and understand what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Kaylie Russell was very lonely in her adolescent years and she was too obsessed with the mirror. She studied all the deaths related to the mirror. She wanted to prove her point to the world by video footage but at the same time she wanted herself and her brother to be safe. So she just eliminated all the possible death reasons, such as dehydration, and set up a schedule to eliminate all the possible ways of death, such as setting up a food and water rationing plan.

Comment: So what I don't like about this answer is the fact she knew the mirror had the ability to affect your mind. A perfect example of this is when her brother tried to smash the mirror. She knew he wouldn't be able to because the mirror would manipulate him into putting the stool down. Another example would be that she knew there would be a radius in which the mirror could have an effect. She wasn't planning to spend week in that house, so starvation and dehydration seem unlikely. Why then did she not wear an aluminum foil hat?

Answer (score 0):

If a profesional hears the story he might say that she was hallucinating because of dehydration or lack of food, the time schedules to eat and drink are to refute this argument against her theory (the mirror being a haunted object).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's mostly to do with logistics, actually. The egg timers that Kaylie is using only go up to a maximum of 60 minutes, and there aren't really a lot of non-electronic timers that can be set for longer than that. If she's trying to prevent dehydration and starvation, it's better to eat too often than not often enough.